# how to set frame delay when use ffmpeg to convert images to gif

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, encode

I want to convert image sequence to gif and I want each frame to last for a certain amount of time, but I couldn't find an example of how to do this.

I know this basic command works

`ffmpeg -y -i %0d_Frame.jpg output.gif`

but how can I let each frame stay for 1 second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is simple:
`ffmpeg -framerate X -y -i %0d_Frame.jpg output.gif`

the order of the commands matters, i have been putting `-framerate` after `-y -i` and it doesn't work that way.

Comment: What if frames vary in duration?

Answer (score 0):

The key managing frame delay in gif creation with ffmpeg is simple: **setpts**

In my code I convert an mp4 file to gif.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=5,split[a][b];[b]palettegen[p];[a][p]paletteuse,setpts=0.5*PTS[v]" -map '[v]' "output.mp4"
```

With **fps** we chose how many frames and wich of them we use for the gif

With **setpts** we chose the delay between frames. 0.5 reduces the delay between frames to half it was in the original file (input.mp4)